# Automatically map asmx-provided xml data to POCO object

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xml-parsing, mapping

In my .net code I am consuming a third-party asmx service that provides me data in Xml format. So basically, I am recieving a structure in a form of XmlNode:

```
<PostcodeEntry>
    <Postcode>13542</Postcode>
    <Postcodename>Odessa</Postcodename>
</PostcodeEntry>
```

Currently, to map it to my POCO object I have to manually iterate through a corresponding ChildNode's and retrieve their InnerText value to get the actual data:

```
 var PostCodeNode = entryNode.SelectSingleNode("Postcode");
 if (PostCodeNode != null)
 {
      result.PostCode = PostCodeNode.InnerText;
 }
```

In case I need to map a large info structure, the code grows to a messy code-scroll.

Is there a way I can improve this so I don't have to write the parsing manually? What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have different options depending on how you get your data and how you like to design your code etc. From your brief description I can think of at least these two:

- Create an XML Serializer - for example by marking up your class with Xml Attributes and de-serialize the XML directly as your desired object via the serializer. The disadvantage of this approach is that you will create a strong coupling between your serializer and your business object. Please take a look at something like this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization.
- Create a proxy object and map your proxy object to your business object. You can create the proxy object either by using a WSDL exposed by the asmx service, or by using the XSD.exe tool or similar (you may need to first generate an XSD based on the XML if the XML is not already described by an XSD). Then you can map the properties of your proxy object to the properties of your business object. This will provide you a more clean separation between the objects, but at the same time it requires more work.

Br. Morten

Answer (score 0):

You can create SoapClient object for WebService, then you can return the Response as List<>. You need to change the Ouput response to List<>.

example Consilder this the webservice to consume, http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/CosmosService/Cm_Service.asmx

then add Service Reference in your application, Click On Advanced Button, change the Collection Type System.Collections.GenericList.

then you can Consume WebService Methods as List<> directly like this

```
CosmosRef.CM_ServiceSoapClient client = new CosmosRef.CM_ServiceSoapClient();

            List<CosmosRef.Product> listProduct = client.GetAllProducts("Computers", 1);
            dataGrid1.DataContext = listProduct;
```